# Force Nuget package dependency to use specific target framework

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project that targets .net 4.0 and has a dependency on [Telnet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telnet).

I've created a nuget package (locally) for my project and added Telnet as a dependency. *However*, when I install this package on a project that targets .net 4.5, nuget installs Telnet for framework 4.5 and because of this my package can do what it was supposed to do, throwing an exception **could not load assembly PrimS.Telnet.40**.

How can I solve this without changing my package project to 4.5 or my target project to 4.0?

Comment: If I understand right what you did is you created a Project1 which references Telnet via Nuget and You create a Nuget package out of Project1 , Now you are referring this project1 as a Nuget reference for some other project let's say project2 ( targeted for .Net framework 4.5 )

Comment: yes, that's it.